# PHP FWRITE - Unable to write to network drive

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, fwrite

I am having an issue to where I can write to the local drive, but not to a network drive... I can copy a files between the 2 computers, but fwrite does not work...

```
   //works
   $myfile = fopen("D:\\mapcycle.txt", 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");

   //Does Not Work, Drive is properly mapped and can copy files from drive to drive via the lan
   $myfile = fopen("X:\\mapcycle.txt", 'w') or die("Unable to open file!"); 

   // Does not work
   $myfile = fopen("\\\\INSURGENCY\\mapcycle.txt", 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
```

I have checked the security between these computer and it seems like it is setup correctly, but not saying I did not miss something.

- Source server: Windows 2008R2, IIS ver 7.0, PHP 5.3.29, MYSQL Ver
  5.5.23
- Destination server: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Check the user that the webserser is run under does have the permissions to write to the drive. 

http://awesometoast.com/php-and-mapped-network-drives/

Comment: Be **VERY** careful with backslashes in `"`-quoted strings. `D:\new\stuff` is actually `D:/[newline]ew/stuff` because of the `\n`. `\m` isn't a metachar (that I know of), but it's still something to be wary of. Don't use ``\`` in PHP paths, even on a Windows box. php will recognize/convert `D:/new/stuff` automatically. Plus make sure that your network drive is mapped for whatever user that PHP is running under. E.g. your webserver's user account may not be a domain account and not have access to the share this drive letter maps to.

Comment: ...and now that the code edit has gone through above, I see you escaped the backslashes anyways, so never mind the first bit of my previous comment. But still, check permissions on the share to see if the webserver user account has access, and that the drive letter is mapped for that user.